# AlpineJS submit form on button click posts the old value instead of the new one

Tags: alpine.js

I'm new to alpineJS, so this might be a silly question. I try to increase an input field by 1, and submit the new value (preferably with a small delay).

I currently have:

```html
<input type='button' 
       value='+' 
       class='qtyplus plus' 
       field='quantity' 
       x-on:click="qty++ && $event.target.form && $event.target.form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'));" />
```

This increases the value of the input form by 1, and submits the form. The problem is that the submitted value is the old value, and not the new one.

Any help with this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more debugging I found the solution by using two on-click events, one that works directly and one that is delayed. This solved the issue for me.

```html
<input type='button' 
       value='-' 
       class='qtyminus minus' 
       field='quantity'
       x-on:click="qty--;" 
       @click.debounce.2000ms="$event.target.form.submit();"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `&&` operator in JavaScript is used to test conditions for true/false. You should instead use `;` to put multiple commands in a single click. JavaScript does some unexpected conversions of values to true/false values. I'm surprised it works even partially. The mysteries of JavaScript!

[MDN has some good info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) on the && operator - called **Logical AND**

Here's your code sample with the change. I also made a couple of other changes using Alpine JS features:

1. [debounce](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on#debounce) might be useful for you as it tells Alpine JS to wait until the user has stopped clicking before it executes the click code - which means your server won't have to process so many requests.
2. [x-ref](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/ref) can be used instead of `$event.target.form` (not useful for you I think, but might be useful for others reading this question)
3. Form elements have a `submit()` method you can use. [MDN has good info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) on this as well.

```html
<form x-ref="myform">
    <input 
        type='button' 
        value='+' 
        class='qtyplus plus' 
        field='quantity' 
        @click.debounce="qty++; $refs.myform.submit()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thx for the  detailed feedback. the problem with this solution is that the quantity only gets added after the 2 seconds, also the refs.myform results in an undefined object error.

after some more debugging I found the solution by using two on-click events, one that works directly and one that is delayed. This solved the issue for me.

<input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus minus' field='quantity'
                               x-on:click="qty--;" @click.debounce.2000ms="$event.target.form.submit();"/>

Comment: Shouldn't the `refs.myform.submit()` be `$refs.myform.submit()`?